# Check if large local file differs from a large file in svn repository

Tags: svn

I would like to check if a large local file `large_file` (about 300MB) differs from a file in a remote subversion repository `svn://server/repo/large_file`. The local file is not part of a checkout if the repository.

I can get the sha checksum of the local file with

```
> svn info large_file | grep Checksum
Checksum: a9d0a9859f0b251d5ea03c6d5cf1d5a65b072127
```

Getting the checksum for the file in the repository, does not work:

```
svn info svn://server/repo/large_file | grep Checksum
```

This is strange because according to a [discussion on the svn users mailing list](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2008-08/0332.shtml) the checksum is stored in the server.

**Rationale:** In the context of machine learning, I'm working on a script that checks that the dependencies of a model are actually coming from the mentioned svn repository.